# Facebook session not destroying on my website

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to destroy a Facebook login session with the php api, but my website session is not destroying even if I logout from Facebook.

Can anyone let me know?

Comment: Code, we need to see what you've done so far

Answer (score 2):

The Facebook PHP SDK creates a session for your application.You can use this function to destroy the session.

```
    function logout()
    {
    $this-> facebook->destroySession();
    }
```